# Image sprites not displaying

Tags: html, css, image, css-sprites

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I've tried following the example on the relevant w3schools page, but to no avail. So here's what I have so far:

I have four images on my index page, called index1.png, index2.png etc. I combined them into a single png, which is simply index.png. That's my sprite image. I also have a 1x1 transparent image, which is the placeholder for each image in the HTML. Here is the image code:

```
<img class="index1" src="Images/trans.png" alt="alt" title="title" width="40%" />
```

And the CSS:

```
img.index1 {
    width:258px;
    height:300px;
    background:url(Images/index.png) 0px 0px;
}
```

Testing the page out, I get nothing more than a resized transparent image. The image I want displayed does not show up.

EDIT: Solved. I was an idiot and forgot to go up one directory in my CSS, since my CSS was in a folder on the root. The proper path was "../Images"

Comment: Is the path to the background image correct? Is browser getting a 200 response when trying to load the background image?

Comment: Your first problem is trying to use w3schools as a resource. Can you give a link to the website? The image path might be wrong

Comment: Wish I could down-vote the comment knocking the w3schools site. Lots of useful stuff there, well organized and free.

Comment: @Gus In some instances they can have good information. But they have lost of information that is false. Linking to someplace like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) would be a safer bet

Comment: if your are following w3schools, chances are you messed up because of them - http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @Gus: If you feel that w3school is useful, you are missing a lot!

Comment: All for MDN, just I rarely have trouble with w3schools. Mostly I use them when I can't recall mundane stuff like which attribute selector syntax is which, and they tend to come up first on Google. Only run into one or two things wrong. I suppose if you were learning from scratch there you would be more likely to find all their mistakes. Anyway, this probably should be chat. YMMV.

Comment: @Gus: Not for MDN at all. But we have better options like http://reference.sitepoint.com/css and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ to compete against http://www.w3schools.com/ and not to mention http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @Jawad hehe did you even look at the link to MDN in Cody Guldner's comment that I was responding to. It's the same as the one you suggested. Also, the w3fools site linked would be more impressive it it had links to actual problematic content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure the path to your images folder is correct?  Make sure your path for your sprite is relative to your CSS file, not from where the CSS file is being linked from.

If you had a folder structure like this:

```
/index.html
/css/style.css
/images/sprite.png
/folder1/index.html
/folder2/subfolder2/index.html
```

The correct path to use in your CSS file would be this: `../images/sprite.png`.

The path would be the same in your CSS file regardless of which `index.html` file that you would be including it from in the example above.

Comment: Man, oh man, am I an idiot. Yes, I overlooked the fact that I needed to go up one directory. Many thanks!

Comment: you are not an idiot mate. it's just the learning curve. +1 to the answer

Answer (score 3):

Try using an element other than `<img>`. A `<div>` element should work fine.

```
<div class="index1" alt="alt" title="title" ></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.index1 {
    width:258px;
    height:300px;
    background:url(Images/index.png) 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the OP's syntax. This wouldn't really change anything

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, seeing as though you're using a sprite `<img>` isn't the correct tag. A div will suffice here. You also don't need to target HTML in your CSS as you've set a class. Try...

```
<div class="index1"></div>
```

Also your image url is missing quotation marks.

```
.index1 { 
    background-image:url('Images/index.png'); 
    background-position: 0 0; 
    height:300px; 
    width:258px; 
 }
```